# How to register a model to AzureML using MLflow from Databricks

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

I'm trying to train the model on Azure Databricks platform and register the model on Azure Machine learning studio to register the model. I have created a service principle to authenticate. Below is the code I'm using. But I'm unable to log experiments or register the model to Azure Machine learning and facing some issue.

```py
from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, RunConfiguration, Environment
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azureml.core.model import Model
subscription_id = ""
resource_group = ""
workspace = ""

srv_prc = ServicePrincipalAuthentication()`

ws = Workspace()
       mlflow.set_tracking_uri("azureml://eastus.api.azureml.ms/mlflow/v1.0/subscriptions//resourceGroups/mlopstest/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/")

mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name='mlopstest1')
```

I have tried using mlflow 2.4 and 2.5 versions

> MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with error code 403 != 200. Response body: ''

Comment: Based on this link , https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/7795#issuecomment-1421604685  You can add : mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://localhost:5000") should be done before any mlflow operation.

Answer (score 0):

This error code: 403 indicates that the request was forbidden, which means that the credentials you are using to authenticate are not authorized to access the resource.

To check your authentications and set up correctly please check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=sdk) and for more details on using service principal authentication in training and tracking of mlfow model please check this [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/using-mlflow/train-and-log/xgboost_service_principal.ipynb)

One you have proper authentication; you can check this [sample notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/using-mlflow/deploy/track_with_databricks_deploy_aml.ipynb) that demonstrate two scenario of `training models in Azure Databricks and deploying them on Azure ML.`

Sample code snippet to set tracking experiment:

```py
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(azureml_tracking_uri)
```

Below is sample code can be use to register the trained model:

```py
client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()
model_path = client.download_artifacts(run.info.run_id, path="model")
mlflow.register_model(
    model_uri=f"file://{model_path}", name="databricks-heart-classifier"
)
```